# Format WPF progress bar decimals

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a progressbar in WPF C# and I bind the text of a textblock to the value of WPF. All in one click, it's great. However, when sliding the slider, the value changes to many many decimals. How can I format this value to have for example 2 numbers behind comma?

UPDATE: The request

```
<Slider x:Name="eqbandwidth" Margin="164.122,111.813,122.564,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Minimum="1" Maximum="36" Value="12"/><TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,95.399,143.134,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=eqbandwidth}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFB6B6B6" FontSize="9.333" TextAlignment="Center"/>
```

results in a value like: 24.656702025072359

To make my question more clear: I want the values to be 24.67 for example.

Comment: It's probably a simple setting, but if you post the code that's autogenerated it will help us (well me) find the correct setting.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.  You mention a progress bar, a textblock, a "click", a slider, and a value.  Where are each of these, and how do they relate to each other in your UI?  What and where is "the value"?

Comment: My best guess is that this might not actually have anything to do with WPF itself, and may just be "how do I format a string, if I am given a decimal".  If this is the case, then please rephrase the question to remove any reference to WPF.

Comment: Well I'm looking for a solution that might be in wpf so that I don't have to code each textblock manually to format the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TextBlock [...] 
           Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=eqbandwidth, StringFormat=N2}" 
           [...] />
```

StringFormat exists since .net 3.0 I think, it takes a normal string formatting string.